# How to style upper left cell of a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I understand to access the top left cell of a dataframe we need to use `df.columns.name` and I can see the pandas document on styling provides example to style row/column headers with `apply_index` (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html)

The question I have is how to style this top left cell, say color it blue. Thanks.

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.columns.name = 'Test'
df
```

Update: ouroboros1's answer below is very informative and helpful. But seems like when converting the Styler object to Excel, i.e. to_excel(), the format to the top left cell is not preserved.

In the documentation (and in Export to Excel section), it is stated that "Table level styles, and data cell CSS-classes are not included in the export to Excel: individual cells must have their properties mapped by the `Styler.apply` and/or `Styler.applymap` methods".

Update: Thanks to @ouroboros1
Here is a possible solution for anyone who is interested.

```py
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
color_matrix_df = pd.DataFrame([['background-color:yellow', 'background-color:yellow'],
                ['background-color:yellow', 'background-color:blue']])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.columns.name = 'Test'
df

def colors(df, color_matrix_df):
    style_df = pd.DataFrame(color_matrix_df.values, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
    return style_df.applymap(lambda elem: elem)

df_upper_left_cell = df.style.set_table_styles(
    [{'selector': '.index_name',
      'props': [('background-color', 'IndianRed'),
                ('color', 'white')]
     }]
)

df_upper_left_cell.apply(colors, axis=None, color_matrix_df=color_matrix_df)

w = pd.ExcelWriter('Test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df_upper_left_cell.to_excel(w, index=True)
wb = w.book
ws = w.sheets['Sheet1']
fmt_header = wb.add_format({'fg_color': '#cd5c5c', 'align': 'center'})
ws.write(0,0, df_upper_left_cell.data.columns.name, fmt_header)
w.save()
```

The above code will color the dataframe as shown below and saved the same to the Excel file.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Styler.set_table_styles`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_styles.html) for this.

We have the following options:

- Top left corner (hereafter: "cell") is empty (no `name` set)
- cell contains either `df.columns.name` or `df.index.name`, or both

Grouped there are three options to style cell (entirely, or partially). I'll walk through them below. First the data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
df
```

Standard look:

[image: df normal]

---

**Option 1.** Cell is empty

Trick is to look at the output for `print(df.style.set_table_styles().to_html())`:

```html
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="blank level0" >&nbsp;</th>
      <th id="T_d7719_level0_col0" class="col_heading level0 col0" >col1</th>
      ...
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

Notice: `<th class="blank level0" >&nbsp;</th>`. We can access these class names and set the format. E.g. in this case, we access `blank` (`level0` applying to all of `level0`, i.e. all cols and index too).

```
df.style.set_table_styles(
    [{'selector': '.blank',
      'props': [('background-color', 'IndianRed'),
                ('color', 'white')]
     }]
)
```

Result:

[image: df normal]

---

**Option 2.** Either `df.columns.name` or `df.index.name`, or both. One style to *entire* cell.

In either scenario, we will need `.index_name` instead of `.blank`. E.g.

```
df.columns.name = 'columns'

df.style.set_table_styles(
    [{'selector': '.index_name',
      'props': [('background-color', 'IndianRed'),
                ('color', 'white')]
     }]
)
```

Result:

[image: df cell with col name]
[image: df cell with index name]
[image: df cell with both col name and index]

---

**Option 3.** `df.columns.name` and `df.index.name`, different styles.

This one is a little more tricky, as we will need to add `tr:nth-child(1)` for `columns.name` and `tr:nth-child(2)` for `index.name`.

```
# just setting col and index name immediately inside `pd.DataFrame`
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,3],[2,4]], 
                  columns=pd.Index(['col1','col2'], name='columns'), 
                  index=pd.Index([0,1], name='index'))

df.style.set_table_styles(
    [{'selector': 'tr:nth-child(1) .index_name',
      'props': [('background-color', 'IndianRed'),
                ('color', 'white')]
     }, {'selector': 'tr:nth-child(2) .index_name',
      'props': [('background-color', '#EECACA'),
                ('color', 'black')]
     }]
)
```

[image: df cell both col index name differently colored]

Comment: @Chenyang: if the answer offers a solution to your problem, please consider accepting it to close the question.

Comment: Hey ouroboros1, your answer is very informative and helpful. But one issue I noticed is when converting the Styler object to Excel, i.e. to_excel(), the format to the top left cell is not preserved; do you have any method to achieve it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with `Styler`. Maybe with [`styleframe`](https://pypi.org/project/styleframe/). But you can also use `pd.ExcelWriter`. E.g. `w = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')`, `df.to_excel(w, index=True)`, `wb = w.book`, `ws = w.sheets['Sheet1']`, `fmt_header = wb.add_format({'fg_color': '#cd5c5c'})`, `ws.write(0,0, 'name', fmt_header)`, `w.save()` (use each code snippet here on a new line). This should get you your df with `A1` filled red and "name" as string (you could put `df.columns.name` here, of course). So, `0,0` just being the coordinates for `A1`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [The Coding Bot: How to colour a specific cell in pandas dataframe based on its position?](https://thecodingbot.com/how-to-colour-a-specific-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-its-position/)

You can use [`style.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) together with an `iloc` for that ***specific cell*** to assign a color.

```
def styling_specific_cell(x,row_idx,col_idx):
    #color = 'background-color: lightblue; color: blue'
    #color = 'color: blue'
    color = 'background-color: lightblue'
    df_styler = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    df_styler.iloc[row_idx, col_idx] = color
    return df_styler

style_idx_row = 0  
style_idx_column = 0   

df.style.apply(styling_specific_cell, row_idx = style_idx_row, col_idx = style_idx_column,
               axis = None)
```

[image]

Change the `#` within the function for font color or both.

---

To see the steps within the function check:

```
print(pd.DataFrame('', index=df.index, columns=df.columns))
print(df.iloc[0,0])
```

---

To assing a color to a ***specific index*** you can use [`style.applymap_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap_index.html):

```
def color_b(v):
    return "background-color: lightblue;" if v == 0 else None

df.style.applymap_index(color_b)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, this code works for coloring cell within 2D data matrix. My original question asks for coloring a specific cell "top left cell" that is left of the column headers and above row headers. Any suggestions there? thanks.

Comment: @Chenyang would that cell be the one containing 'Test' in your example?

Comment: Hi Magnus, yes, that the Cell I am referring to.

Comment: @Chenyang ok, then ouroboros1 has answered your question in the meantime